# How to create a notification in MS Word if attachment is missing

Tags: microsoft-word, images, attachments

I create daily reports in MS Word (2019). Some of the reports require an image attachment in the word document. I often forget to include the attachment. I need to create a script or macro that checks to see if the image is included, every time I close the document. If an image is not included, it will let me know via prompt or flag.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a MS [Word document **template**](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Word-Template) from an existing valid report, but replacing the inline image with an image of the same size with text, "**INSERT IMAGE HERE**". This will also make the task of creating consistent, professional-looking documents easier.

Or

2. Assuming the output file can be edited, and assuming an image greatly increases the file size, run a script that checks file size, and alerts you if the file is too small.

Comment: Brilliant. I’ll give that a try!

Comment: Let us know if either work for you. Thanks.